# Obtaining the endpoint details in Apache Camel

Tags: java, spring, soap, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

Having the setup of round robin mechanism in order to choose the endpoints , how can we obtain the endpoint to which the camel router had sent the request to?

This question would be more easy to 
For example,

> say I have 3 end points to which the router is pointed to.I want to
>   obtain to which endpoint the request has gone to? tried few inbuilt
>   methods of producer template to retrieve them

. But nothing turned up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find the endpoint uri as exchange property with the key `CamelToEndpoint`

Comment: @ClausIbsen I was able to obtain the same from `exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelCxfMessage");` . But here there is a problem. I am unable to fetch the endpoint details when there is a socketTimeOut. Is there a way to get the endpoint details in this case ?